# Usage of apply plugin: 'application' tag in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am starting to explore gradle and the question might be naive. 
I have noted from the gradle docs about below plugin-

```
apply plugin: 'application'
The Application plugin facilitates creating an executable JVM application. It makes it easy to start the application locally during development.
Applying the Application plugin also implicitly applies the Java plugin.
```

I want to understand if the below plugin entry is mandatory as I have not seen it in many projects. Also if this is used to make the jar runnable/creating executable JVM application. Does that mean skipping does not make the application executable ?

Answer (score 0):

The `'application'` plugin is not mandatory when creating an executable JVM application, it facilitates the creation of one.

You can use other plugins to create a runnable jar, one of them is [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

If you know how the structure of the runnable jar should look like, You can do everything on your own and pack needed libraries for small apps or testing by extending the jar task from `Java` plugin.

```
jar {
archiveName = 'Name.jar'

manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main',
            'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
            'Implementation-Version': project.version (if any)
}

from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
}
```

**I would suggest using the application plugin. its supported, its Gradle, it's recommended by other developers.**

Applying the [Application](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin also implicitly applies the Java plugin. The main source set is effectively the “application”. And it facilitates the creation of the runnable jar application.

The [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) adds Java compilation along with testing and bundling capabilities to a project. It serves as the basis for many of the other Gradle plugins.

---

To simply answer your question:

Application plugin is one (recommended) of the ways to help you with runnable JVM app creation.

Comment: I have seen only apply plugin: 'java' being used in pom files, does it also create executable JVM application ? if yes then is there any specific case to go with application plugin ?

Comment: you don't apply Gradle plugins in pom files, no java plugin doesn't create a runnable application, but you can extend the jar task to do it, please read my answer carefully.